# "This site is on hold" when attempting to replace root site

Tags: sharepoint, replace, sharepoint-online, root, swap

I need to replace my SharePoint root site with a newly created team site without office 365 roups.

When I tried to replace my newly created site with a root site it threw me This site is on hold error.

Below are the screenshots for the same.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have **Retention Policies** set on your SharePoint site.

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Sign in the [Microsoft 365 Compliance](https://compliance.microsoft.com/) as a Global Administrator

2.**Information governance** >> **Retention policies**

[image]

3.Select the Retention policy and click **Edit**

4.Check if the Retention policy applies to SharePoint sites.

[image]

5.If yes, you need delete this policy.

**Reference:**

- [Learn about retention policies and retention labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/retention?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: I'm glad I can help you solve the problem. If the answer is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.